# Creating blogs in each page of my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I want to create a website with Wordpress. It has to be divided in sections; each one has to have its stand-alone blog. Nothing but a "welcome" post has to be in the Home. How can I do that? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Try something and get back here. Thanks

Comment: If I post something, it'll appear in the Home and the Pages I created only collect a certain kind of posts (e.g. astronomy) and show them together. I want to have the Home free from posts and I also need each section to work independently.

Answer (score 0):

Select manage themes and select customize and then select static front page which one you want to display in the home page.Now create a page and in page attributes instead of selecting default template select the blog that show all your blog posts in that page.